# scheme : What's imperative features?

Tags: scheme

The bottom code is to remove adjacent duplicate elements from a sorted list L.

```
(define a
  (lambda (L)
    (cond
       ((null? L) L)
       ((null? (cdr L)) L)
       ((eqv? (car L) (car (cdr L))) (a (cdr L)))
       (else (cons (car L) (a (cdr L)))))))
```

Question is "Write a similar function that uses the imperative features of Scheme to modify L 'in place,' rather than building a new list. Compare that to the code above in terms of brevity, conceptual clarity, and speed.

But I don't understand clearly what imperative features. Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for you to use some or all of the following procedures to write the solution: [`set-car!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html?q=set-car%21#%25_idx_416), [`set-cdr!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html?q=set-car%21#%25_idx_418), [`set!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html?q=set%21&q=set-car%21#%25_idx_104), etc. In this context, the *imperative features* refer to those Scheme procedures that mutate data - using them you can modify a list structure "in place", meaning: without creating a new list, instead directly modifying the list passed as parameter.

Notice that all the procedures' names mentioned end with a `!` (pronounced: bang!), this is to warn the programmer that they will change the object received as parameter. Contrast this with the procedures you've been using up until now, that won't change the object and if necessary will return a new object with the requested modification - a *functional programming style*, unlike the *imperative programming style* that will happen when you start using bang!-procedures.

Take a look at section [3.3 Modeling with Mutable Data](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%_sec_3.3) in the SICP book, it will explain in detail how to deal with operations that mutate data.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to do. It's really hard to use scheme, not C.

Comment: I try to solve this problem with set-car, set-cdr, set but it's not work. Actually I'm not sure I understand it correctly

Comment: Think about how you'd solve it in C, using sinle-linked list. It's _exactly_ the same!

Comment: Umm..I think I solve it but it doesn't work. I just change last two line (a (cdr L )) to (a (set! L (cdr L))) and else (a (cdr L)). It's wrong?

Comment: So compared to Clojure, are Scheme and Common Lisp not purely functional? Both kinda encourage side effects, in Clojure I did not use any side effects (except at the very beginning and very end), though in larger projects that may be necessary.

Comment: @PostSelf none of the languages you mention (including Clojure) is purely functional. Using them in that way is more a matter of convention. For a purely functional experience, try Haskell.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I guess I meant that Clojure is not imperative, nor object-oriented